# Delete button for each dynamically created row in a table without using onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple function objects declared from the same function that deal with their own tables with dynamically added rows.  I need to have a delete button of some kind for each row. Since there can be multiple of these objects, the row must know what object it is a part of, and the object could be nested in some arbitrary scope inside other objects (and out of reach of some arbitrary function declaration, I think?), the typical solution of an onClick referencing some other javascript function doesn't seem sufficient.  I've got a setup using delegate to catch the click, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  Here's some example code:

```
function testobject() {
 //other stuff

 $stateadd.click(function() {
  if ($stateselect.val() in states) { //already in array

  } else {
   $temp = $("<tr><td nowrap>" + USStates[$stateselect.val()].Name + "</td><td><input type=\"button\" class=\"testthing\" value=\"Remove\" /></td>").appendTo($selectedstates);
   $temp2 = $temp.find('.testthing');

   $temp.delegate($temp2, 'click', function(e) {
    //how to know what row to delete?  how to know which object the row is in?
    alert($(e.target).attr('class')); //returns proper class, so I can get the button object itself
   });

   states[$stateselect.val()] = $temp;
  }
 });

 //other stuff
}
```

To be clearer, I need two things in the click event: the testobject instance that made the row, and the $stateselect.val() id associated with that row.  I can't just delete the row tr/td tags, I need to have it removed from the states object as well.

Comment: "the typical solution of an onClick referencing some other javascript function doesn't seem sufficient." Why not? That's how I would do it. It's not hard to determine where the button is when the click event is fired.

Comment: @Diodeus I assume they want to avoid defining event handlers using inline attributes on their elements, which definitely isn't a bad thing. Besides, there's not going to be much difference in what the function does so how it's bound to the event shouldn't matter.

Comment: Because I need to get the instance of testobject that made the row, and the $stateselect.val() that was associated with the row when I made it.  How can I obtain that?

Comment: I agree. Using .on() would be a good choice for this solution.

Comment: You can store the value of $stateselect.val() as data in the element itself: $(this).data('stateselect',$stateselect.val()) and read it back later.

Comment: But how do I know the right states object to use it in?  There could be any number of these testobjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the element which is clicked and then you can find the corresponding parent `tr` element using jQuery `closest()` method.

Also the first argument of `delegate` is the selector on which the delegated event should work. You were passing a jQuery object so it didn't work. Try this.

```
$('tableSelector').delegate('.testthing', 'click', function(e) {
    //Here "this" will point to the remove button.

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');//this will give you the corresponding row  
});
```

jQuery `closest()` gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

If you are using latest jQuery ver(1.7+) you can use `on` method.

```
$('tableSelector').on('click', '.testthing', function(e) {
    //Here "this" will point to the remove button.

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');//this will give you the corresponding row  
});
```

Note: You should keep this code outside `testobject` method because you don't need to add `delegate` or `on` everytime you call `testobject` method.

**Update:** Based on the comments

Add a data attribute to the input remove button with stateselect value.

```
$temp = $('<tr><td nowrap>' + USStates[$stateselect.val()].Name + '</td><td><input type="button" data-stateid="' + $stateselect.val() + '" class="testthing" value="Remove" /></td>').appendTo($selectedstates);
```

Js change

```
$('tableSelector').delegate('.testthing', 'click', function(e) {
    //Here "this" will point to the remove button.

    var sateId = $(this).data('sateid');
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');//this will give you the corresponding row  

    //Here you can access states[stateId] and do what you want
});
```

Comment: In case you missed it, `$(this)` in context of delegate is what threw the click event. In this case your button. Also notice how he uses `closest` instead of `parent().parent()` or `parents()` because it is more efficient.

Comment: I can't just remove the row tr, I need to remove its entry from the states object.  That requires me to have the correct instance of testobject and the $stateselect.val() that was inputted as the key value for the states object.

Comment: @user173342 - You can find the stateselect value using `$tr.find('td:first').text()`

Comment: That value is an index, but the value in the td is a string from an array that was accessed from that index.  Also, alone that value is worthless to me, I need to be able to access the states object in some instanced testobject, then use that index value as the key to remove the entry from the states object.

Comment: While appending the remove button you can add a `data-attribute` to `input` element and then retrieve it inside click handler. Use that as key and remove the entry from `states` object.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Nevermind - having re-read your answer, I finally spotted the difference between your code and the code in the question (which would provide the wrong `this`). Going to delete my other comments.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/kYPS3/1/, hope this clears your understanding on `delegate`.

Comment: I still can't see how I can get the proper states object.  I have the data attribute being added, but that's it.  Just to be clear, I really don't care at all about getting the tr.  The states object has that tr as its value, so all that closest stuff in your code doesn't have much of a use.  It's the correct states object that I need...

Answer (score 0):

> "how to know what row to delete?"

you can finding the nearest `<tr>`

like `$(this).closest('tr')` and that will be the row to delete.

simply add to the end of that line

```
slideUp('slow', function() { 
    // now that you have slided Up, let's remove it from the DOM
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

so, you could simply remove the click part and add this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.testthing', function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).attr('class'));

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.slideUp('slow', function() { 
        // now that you have slided Up, let's remove it from the DOM
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.testthing').on()` is not going to work. `'.testthing'` is added dynamically.

Comment: `true` ... was talking with the wife and `on` keyword was been added :)

Comment: `live` is depricated from latest version(1.7+) onwards, worth making a note of it.

Comment: so, that why I had written `on`... even without thinking I can write good code :P